# Add commas in place of number with sed?

Tags: shell, text-formatting, json, numeric-data

Trying to write a simple script to fetch ethereum price and format the response.

Here is what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

response=$(curl 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=GBP')
price=$(echo $response | grep -o -P '(?<=:).*(?=})')
formattedPrice=$(echo "${price%.*}" | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)/\1,\2,\3/g')

echo "£$formattedPrice"
```

Although it doesn't add the commas.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to format the number with `sed`, consider just using `printf`:

```
$ price=1254.43
$ printf "%'.2f\n" $price
1,254.43
```

Or if you don't want the decimal component:

```
$ printf "%'d\n" ${price%.*}
1,254
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq` to extract the number out from the JSON document returned from `curl`, and then GNU `awk` for formatting the number according to the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale since `jq` does not have a `printf` equivalent output filter:

```bash
curl -s 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=GBP' |
jq -r '.GBP' |
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 gawk '{ printf "£%'\''.2f\n", $1 }'
```

The `printf` format string `£%'.2f`, here mangled a bit since the apostrophe in a single-quoted string needs special treatment, would format the integer part of the value by separating the thousands with a comma (in the given locale). It would also add a pound sign (£) before the value and ensure that the value was reported with two decimals.

Example output:

```
£1,262.08
```